# How to convert hexBinary (MsgId) to character in esql?

Tags: ibm-mq, messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I'm trying to put MQMD.MsgId to XMLNSC.MsgId field, like this:

> SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.Root.MsgId = InputRoot.MQMD.MsgId;

But I'm getting *X'414d51204d39392e5352442e4330302e56c47bd4203b3708'* instead of just *414d51204d39392e5352442e4330302e56c47bd4203b3708*.

Also i've tried to cast MsgId to CHARACTER, but result is the same.

How to get rid of quotes and 'X'?

Comment: You have your answer below, but please bear in mind that the MsgId field is a binary field, This means that if you move character data in the MsgID field between platforms where data conversion is required, the MsgId field is NOT converted.

Comment: Thanks, I just thought that there is more pretty solution then using substring.

Comment: Did you mean to put that comment there. Doesn't make any sense. Do you understand the implications of data conversion - or rather the lack of it?

Comment: Actually the OP has a point. This topic provides XML-specific ways to serialize all of the XML Schema types except for hexBinary ( which is what they want ).
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac67192_.htm?lang=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
DECLARE msgId CHARACTER CAST(InputRoot.MQMD.MsgId AS CHARACTER);
SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.Root.MsgId = SUBSTRING(msgId FROM 3 FOR LENGTH(msgId) - 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to 'add a commment' yet, but working with so many languages, I've learned to dislike SUBSTRING and LENGTH type functions. In the case of answer 'Feb 28 2016 at 10:41' above (yes I found this answer in response to my own search - for the "CAST(InputRoot.MQMD.MsgId AS CHAR)" above, I chose to use this instead:

```
DECLARE MsgId CHAR RIGHT(LEFT(CAST(InputRoot.MQMD.MsgId AS CHAR),50),48);
```

This assumes MsgId is always 24 hex pairs long (24x2=48) and goes for LEFT 50 first (taking off the last single quote), then RIGHT 48 (taking off the first X char and the first single quote). Does anyone disagree with the assumption? It also has the bonus of condensing to one line as it's not necessary to have two references to "MsgId" in 'SUBSTRING'

Answer (score 1):

With ESQL SUBSTRING you can also use BEFORE and AFTER

```
DECLARE MsgIdAsChar CHAR SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(CAST(InputRoot.MQMD.MsgId AS CHAR) AFTER '''') BEFORE '''');
```

BEFORE and AFTER are also extremely handy when it comes to looking for things in strings.

```
DECLARE TheHaystack CHAR ‘Where a value is 99 out of a maximum value of 100);
DECLARE TheValue CHAR SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(TheHaystack AFTER 'value is ') BEFORE ' ');
```